# Is there a way to dynamically use setExtreme in Highchart?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement scroll on  X axis by clicking buttons on Highchart. I have set the number of x axis columns using max parameter in x axis options. I am trying to implement the scroll feature by using setExtreme()event. But how do I do the same if I have data array of different sizes?

I have attached the code below.

```js
    let data = {
      "sample": [
        { "item": "ABC", "faults": [{ "fault": "A", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "B", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "C", "actual": 30 }, { "fault": "D", "actual": 50 }, { "fault": "E", "actual": 40 }, { "fault": "F", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "G", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "H", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "I", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "J", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "K", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "L", "actual": 10 }] }, { "item": "XYZ", "faults": [{ "fault": "A", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "B", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "C", "actual": 30 }, { "fault": "D", "actual": 50 }, { "fault": "E", "actual": 40 }, { "fault": "F", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "G", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "H", "actual": 10 }] }, { "item": "RST", "faults": [{ "fault": "A", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "B", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "C", "actual": 30 }, { "fault": "D", "actual": 50 }, { "fault": "E", "actual": 40 }, { "fault": "F", "actual": 20 }, { "fault": "G", "actual": 10 }, { "fault": "H", "actual": 10 }] }]
    }


    let processchart = new Array;
    let valuechart = new Array;
    let idealchart = new Array;
    let variancechart = new Array;
    let scatterchart = new Array;

    function choosemachine(string) {
      processchart.length = valuechart.length = idealchart.length = variancechart.length = 0


      for (i = 0; i < data.sample.length; i++) {
        if (data.sample[i].item == string)
          for (j = 0; j < data.sample[i].faults.length; j++) {
            processchart.push(data.sample[i].faults[j].fault)
            valuechart.push(data.sample[i].faults[j].actual)
          }
      }
    }

    var chart;
    function init() {
      chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {

        xAxis: {
          categories: processchart,
          max: 3
        },
        yAxis: [{
          title: {
            text: ''
          }
        }, {
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          visible: false,
          minPadding: 0,
          maxPadding: 0,
          max: 100,
          min: 0,
          opposite: true,
          labels: {
            format: "{value}%"
          }
        }],
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
            }
          },
        },
        labels: {
          items: [{
            style: {
              left: '50px',
              top: '18px',
              color: 'black'
            }
          }]
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Name',
            type: 'column',
            pointPadding: 0.35,
            zIndex: 2,
            data: valuechart
          }]
      },
        function (chart) {

          var button1 = chart.renderer.text('<button class="text-button"><</button>', 600, 60, true)
            .on('click', function () {
              chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 2);
            })
            .add();

          var button2 = chart.renderer.text('<button class="text-button">></button>', 650, 60, true)
            .on('click', function () {
              chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(3, 6);
            })
            .add()

        });

    }

    choosemachine("ABC")
    init();


    document.getElementById("options").addEventListener('change', function () {
      choosemachine(document.getElementById("options").value)
      init();
    })
```

```css
 .card {
      height: 400px;
      width: 800px;
      background: #2A2E33 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
      opacity: 1;

    }

    .title {
      background-color: black;
      height: 60px;
      color: white;
    }



    #container {
      height: 400px;
      width: 800px;
      left: 500px;
    }

    .highcharts-background {
      fill: #2A2E33;

    }

    .highcharts-data-table table {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 10px auto;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
    }

    .highcharts-data-table caption {
      padding: 1em 0;
      font-size: 1.2em;

    }

    .highcharts-data-table th {
      font-weight: 600;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }


    .highcharts-yaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #353333;
    }

    .highcharts-yaxis .highcharts-tick {
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #353333;
      color: whitesmoke;
    }

    .highcharts-minor-grid-line {
      stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/dumbbell.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/lollipop.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pareto.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: grey;">



  <div class="card">
    <div class="title">


      <select id="options" style="float:right;margin:20px;">
        <option id="ABC" value="ABC">ABC</option>
        <option id="XYZ" value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
        <option id="RST" value="RST">RST</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this kind of configuration:

- button right adds, for example, a 3 to the xAxis min and max,
- button left subtracts a 3 from the xAxis min and max,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vahwynmd/

```
function(chart) {

  var button1 = chart.renderer.text('<button class="text-button"><</button>', 200, 60, true)
    .on('click', function() {
      let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];

      xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.min - 3, xAxis.max - 3);
    })
    .add();

  var button2 = chart.renderer.text('<button class="text-button">></button>', 250, 60, true)
    .on('click', function() {
      let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];

      xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.min + 3, xAxis.max + 3);
    })
    .add()

});
```